# JavaScript validation - not working on text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onchange

Trying to run some Javascript validation on a form but nothing is working. An alert should be issued, stopping the user from proceeding with booking a seat, but they can continue freely. Not sure what i'm doing wrong, but it seems quite basic.

If someone could take a look at my code, I would appreciate it.

Form for text input >>>

```
<form method="POST" name="Customer_Details" action="Ice Cream.php">
    <h3> Full Name </h3>
    <p> Name - Full Name. </p>
    <input type="text" name="Name" oninput="nameCheck();" />

    <h3> Email Address </h3>
    <p> Email here please </p>
    <input type="text" name="Email" oninput="return(validateEmail());" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book Tickets">
</form>
```

Javascript for validateEmail();

```
var email = document.Customer_Details.Email;

function validateEmail(email)  
{  
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
    if(email.value.match(mailformat))  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address. Please try again!");  
        email.focus();  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? Why did you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Your var email  is not the argument of your validate email function.
This function doesn't need any argument:

```
function validateEmail()  
{  
    email = document.Customer_Details.Email;
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
    if(email.value.match(mailformat))  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address. Please try again!");  
        email.focus();  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

(But the oniput use makes it difficult to enter an email ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is that your javascript validation is being called in the wrong place. It should be called when the form is submitted.

This code worked when I tested it:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" name="Customer_Details" action="Ice Cream.php" onsubmit="return validateEmail()">
    <h3> Full Name </h3>
    <p> Name - Full Name. </p>
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <h3> Email Address </h3>
    <p> Email here please </p>
    <input type="text" name="Email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book Tickets">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validateEmail() {
    var email = document.Customer_Details.Email;

    if(!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.value)) {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;  
    }  
}
```